# Which Soviet leader has said "there is censorship in the West too - it's called money"!

Tags: soviet-union, media

I vaguely remember hearing a quote from soviet leader (might be Gorbachev, could be someone else), acknowledging media censorship in the Eastern bloc but arguing there is censorship in the West as well, in the form of money (as in ownership of mass media by the ruling class). This was probably late 1980s, which is why I'm assuming Gorbachev, but I can't find any reference to this. More vaguely I would remember this happening in some discussion between US and USSR leaders.

I would be happy to know if my memory serves me right, ie if such statement was ever given officially or unofficially, and in what circumstance?

Comment: I don't recall seeing this exact quote, but, starting with Marx, communists always refused to differentiate between _economic_ and _physical_ coercion. Specifically, they claimed that the proletarians in a capitalist society were enslaved because they were coerced to work in order to survive.
How is that different from the _socialist_ slogan "_those who do not work, do not eat_" -- beats me.

Comment: I'm not sure about Soviet times, but idea that there is unofficial (mostly financial ) censorship in the West is live and well in Russia . Found couple of articles in Russian on yandex.ru about the issue, someone with better understanding of language would probably do better : https://zen.yandex.ru/media/mamin_sibiryak/est-li-svoboda-slova-v-evrope-i-ssha-5cae3dc3a88be900b9649aea?utm_source=serp               https://maxpark.com/community/4109/content/5536911